# Jquery color wont switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to build a very simple piece of code for when you click a `<td>` it will turn black but when you click it again it will turn white.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){
        if($(this).css('background-color') != 'black'){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
        }
        else if($(this).css('background-color') === 'black'){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
        }
    });
});
```

With this code it will turn black but wont turn white again.

Comment: Any log in console ?

Comment: Why `else if` just `else` will do.

Comment: `$(this).css('background-color')` will only return a value if it was previously set.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan in which case the `if` will be true.

Comment: this will return an rgb value check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pjnu8L1g/... you can use toggleClass as an alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't turn white again because `"black"` is just a shortcut. The browser is converting that to `rgb(0, 0, 0)` which is not absolutely-strictly-equal ([`==` vs. `===`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)) to "black"

See this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uxnrfh3c/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span").click(function() {
        alert($(this).css('background-color')); // alerts rgb(0, 0, 0)
        if($(this).css('background-color') != 'black') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
        }
        else if($(this).css('background-color') === 'black') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this works for chrome but not firefox that is the only issue

Comment: @Ricky_Woessner Then you can't detect the color this way and need to store your state somewhere else, like in Ilya Zinkevych's answer.  Or do multiple checks, `if(color == rgb(0,0,0) || coloor == "black")` (or whatever Firefox treats the value as). There are a lot of options here. I've given you why it doesn't work AND a metehod to figure out what the value IS, its up to you now to take that information and fix your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make a flag which coresponds to state of your element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let state = true;
  $("td").click(function(){
    if(state) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
      state = false;
    } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
      state = true;
    }
  });
});
```